# rails cart id show issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I cannot get my cart icon to link to the user's actual cart without plugging the exact numerical id in. Here is my code that I want to link to a display of the user's cart:

```
<li class="navtxt"id='cart-button'><%= link_to(image_tag("cart.png"),@cart)%></li>
```

And at the moment, all it does is flash the screen momentarily and bring me back to the top of the homepage.

My carts controller show begins with:

```
def show
 begin
  @cart = Cart.find(params[:id])
```

With a CurrentCart method in my application controller, which is included in my carts controller:

```
 private

 def current_cart 
   Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
 rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
   cart = Cart.create
   session[:cart_id] = cart.id
   cart
 end
```

and

```
resources :carts
```

in routes.rb

Any insight? Thanks. I have this open, so if there's any code that can help lead to a solution I'll be immediate with it.

Edit- added preceding code

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :invalid_cart
# GET /carts/1
# GET /carts/1.xml
```

Comment: Can you explain your issue again? What you mean by this: `I cannot get my cart icon to link to the user's actual cart without plugging the exact numerical id in`

Comment: @Mandeep I can look in my terminal and see that the cart has an id of 50, so when I plug that into parentheses next to "@cart", it works.  My question is what code to plug in to know that ID automatically, so when that icon is clicked their own cart shows.

Comment: @cart.id will give you id of your current_cart but i still didn't get what you are trying to do. You want to show an image as a link to show your current cart?

Comment: @Mandeep the image is irrelevant, I am just wondering what the proper code is to link from the navbar cart icon to the user's current cart

Comment: @Mandeep when I type in "@cart.id" I get undefined method 'Id" for nilclass

Comment: that's because you didn't set @cart in your controller action. What action are you in?

Comment: `@cart` is nil...  Does your `find` fail?  Are you rescuing and hiding an error?  Also, I don't see where you use `current_cart`.

Comment: @NickVeys i think that is the show action of cart and hence irrelevant in this case

Comment: In my carts show action there is "@cart", is that not being set? Here is some preceding code. class CartsController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :invalid_cart
# GET /carts/1
# GET /carts/1.xml

Comment: @alex in which template you have this code `<li class="navtxt"id='cart-button'><%= link_to(image_tag("cart.png"),@cart)%></li>`

Comment: @Mandeep in my _navigation.html.erb

Comment: @alex and where are you rendering this partial? I want to know which action you are currently in. You need to set your cart in that action

Comment: @Mandeep I have the _navigation.html.erb in views/shared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<li class="navtxt"id='cart-button'>
  <%= link_to @cart do %>
    <%= image_tag("cart.png") %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

and since you want to show your cart in navigation so it'll be better to set in application controller. You can do it by:

```
before_filter :set_cart 

def set_cart 
  @cart = current_cart 
end
```

Comment: I added some preceding code on the main question, does that help?

Comment: Always remember @Mandeep, you are my hero.